# Can't connect to localhost via browser. Can ping localhost

Tags: localhost

I’m trying to connect to `localhost` through my browser to learn some Apache Tomcat stuff.

When I tried to connect to localhost through Firefox, I couldn’t; when I tried through Internet Explorer, I could the first time, but not after that.

I’m using Windows 7, and changed the hosts file to point localhost to `127.0.0.1`. I can successfully ping localhost and `127.0.0.1`.

I have tried turning off my antivirus and my Windows Firewall, but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do your Apache logs indicate that the connection request is even getting through to the httpd daemon?

Comment: I'm not sure and don't know how to check. Tomcat seems to start up fine per the catalina logs other than a couple "Cannot find message associated with key ..." lines that aren't supposed to be a problem, and I do get a "Server startup in 2421 ms" message that, I think, indicates I have a good connection.

Comment: tomcat is probably running as java.exe in your process list, btw.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem comes from your Tomcat and Apache configurations.

When you type in `localhost` into Internet Explorer, it automatically suposes you're connecting to port 80.

You’re going to have to make sure that Apache is correctly configured to work with Tomcat.

You can also try out your tomcat server by connecting to:

```
 http://localhost:portNumber
```

That is, add the port number you’ve configured TomCat for after a colon… Try `http://localhost:8080` for a start.

Comment: Was going to say the same thing but that doesn't tie in with it working first time in IE and then not working again. Unless the installer opened up the page automatically when it finished.

Comment: Hi akseli. I should have mentioned that I already tried http://localhost:8080 and http://localhost:80 in both browsers.

Comment: Also, the connector port for tomcat's server.xml is pointing to 8080.

Comment: Can you telnet onto port 8080 via command prompt?

Comment: Hi Ciaran. I don't think so. Typing "telnet localhost 8080" gets me a message reading, "Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8080: Connect failed"

Comment: That would mean that Apache isn't listening on port 8080 or that something is blocking the path to it. I would double check from the services snap-in (start > run > services.msc) that Apache is running. Failing that, restart Apache. Failing that, turn off all protection software and try again. If/when you restart Apache, hit F5 to refresh the grid and check the status again because it could start/stop immediately

Comment: Didn't work. I tried restarting apache and running it w/o antivirus or WIndows firewall or Defender running, and did the F5 thing. Still no dice.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a clue to my problem, but when I try to hit http://localhost:8080 and watch it in Firebug, the status for "GET localhost:8080" is Aborted. What are the things that can abort the request if antivirus, spyware, and firewall are all turned off? I's a-confused.

Comment: Just posted an answer which I hope will help more

Answer (score 2):

Run `tasklist` from command prompt and note the process ID for Tomcat

Run `netstat -noa` and look for the the process ID you noted above. The 2nd column should show you something like `0.0.0.0:xxxxx`. If there is an entry here for the process ID for Tomcat then Tomcat is definitely listening for connections properly. If not, Tomcat's broken and you may need to reinstall it or dive into the Tomcat logs (since it seems to be running but not listening properly).

There might be a few entries for the process ID, each giving a different port. Try them all because I believe you can forward one port to another in Tomcat.

Comment: When running tasklist, I don't see anything about tomcat or apache, but using netstat, I see that some ports have a LISTENING state, but that 127.0.0.1:8080 and 127.0.0.1:80 aren't in the list at all, so I assume that those ports aren't listening. I then tried to ping 127.0.0.1:8080 and 127.0.0.1:80 and that doesn't come back, while 127.0.0.1 does. Have I turned off the 80 and 8080 ports somehow?

Comment: If you don't see anything about Tomcat or Apache then they probably aren't running or might have a different process name. If you're using Windows Vista or Windows 7 you can open up task manager instead, click the services tab, right click the Apache/Tomcat service and click go to process (only available if the service is actually running). You can get the process ID from there if the column is visible. If not, go to view > select columns... > check the PID checkbox

Comment: You can't ping an address with a port number on the end. telnet is the way to find out if the port is listening. I'm convinced that Apache/Tomcat isn't actually running btw, if it wasn't in tasklist

Comment: I'm going to reinstall Tomcat and see if that does anything.

Comment: Were you able to verify if a process existed in task manager for it?

Comment: No, there was no process for it in task manager. I wonder if that might be because of the way I downloaded tomcat before. I'm looking at the documentation for the downloads page, and it seems that if you get the .zip file, "These distributions do not include the Windows service wrapper nor the compiled APR/native library for Windows." Is that Winddows service wrapper what would make it visible in task manager? Getting tomcat via the .exe includes that Windows service wrapper. Could it be that tomcat really is running but just doesn't show that via Windows reporting tools.

Comment: I should mention that the documentation I was looking at was for Tomcat 7 while I have 5. I went and looked at 5's docs and it doesn't mention the WIndows service wrapper. Think I'll grab 7 now.

Comment: Not really possible that it would be running but not showing in task manager under processes or services (well we know it's not a service now anyway). If you were to get the exe installer, it would register itself as a service. Doesn't explain why you weren't seeing it in task manager though. My guess is you ran either startup.bat or tomcat7.exe and it popped up a console window and closed it down straight away? If so, you missed an error that you would see if you ran it from an open command prompt.

Comment: Now, I'm really confused. I got tomcat 7 and was able to have the http://localhost:8080 page come up in my browser. I think I hit another link that took me to a valid page (not sure), then tried another link that didn't work. I hit my back button and saved the URL from that page - http://localhost:8080/docs/setup.html. After this, any link I followed gave me the "Unable to connect" error. I could still hit the setup page I had first hit, but when I cleared my browser cache, I couldn't even get that page to come up. Btw, I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: Whenever you get the generic "unable to connect" Firefox message, double check everything you've done so far like being able to telnet to localhost port 8080, checking if the process is running, use netstat to see if it's listening on the correct port, etc.

Comment: I think it may actually have been showing up in Task Manager's services. It shows up as conhost.exe and java.exe. I was looking for tomcat or apache in the title. It shows up under the Applications tab. I'm not sure if I looked in that tab before. That still doesn't explain why I could hit localhost a while ago, then couldn't. This has got me going in circles.

Comment: conhost and java would probably have been there anyway. The Tomcat process running on my machine is called tomcat6.exe. Just remember to keep checking things in the right order. First, Tomcat has to be running, i.e. it has to have it's own process, then check if it's listening on the right port, then see if you can get to it in a web browser.

Comment: I can now hit localhost with the tomcat7 I got yesterday, but not with the tomcat5.5 of old. Even when tomcat7 is serving pages from localhost, I still don't see mention of tomcat running as a process via tasklist or as a process under the Task Manager, but I can hit localhost again (though I don't know what's changed from yesterday when I couldn't hit it with either 5.5 or 7.) &pheww;

Comment: Well, glad it's running but I don't understand why you're not seeing a process called tomcat. Strange one

Comment: I don't know either. Thanks for showing me tasklist and netstat. Those are going to be good to know.